# What is the best way to store HTML markup as a string

Tags: php, html, string

For a wordpress shortcode I have to return a string containing HTML markup and I'm wondering what the best way to build/store it is.

My first attempt was an unreadable mess of concatenated parts like this:

```
$output = '<div ';
if( $atts['ID'] ) { 
  $output .= 'id="'.$atts['ID'].'"'; 
}
$output .= ' class="responsive-map icon-'.$atts['icon'].'"';
```

Thanks to `sprintf()` I could trim it down into a much more readable shape:

```
$format = '
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div %1$s class="ie responsive-map %2$s" %3$s>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
    <div %1$s class="responsive-map %2$s" %3$s>
<!--<![endif]-->
        <iframe src="%4$s"></iframe>
    </div>
';

$output = sprintf( $format, $id, $icon, $height, $content );
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this, especially if the complexity of the markup and number of variable parts goes up. Usually I would simply escape the HTML but in this case that is not an option as wordpress will always place the escaped HTML at the top of a post rather than the intended placement.

Comment: The best way is to *not* store HTML markup as a string.

Comment: I'm not into `WordPress` but isn't there any `partial\template` functionality in this framework? IMO That's the best approach.

Comment: `DomDocument` and `SimpleXML` are your friends and the best way to store markup as an object.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to use templates for shortcodes or to be more precise not returning the markup as a string will mess up the order of elements ie `content-shortcode-content` will become `shortcode_output-content-content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a better approach then storing the HTML in template at all could be to use a template engine, using template files.

---

While you could use a double quoted multiline string, I would use a [here document](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). You can interpolate variables like in a double quoted string:

```
$format = <<<EOF
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div $variable1 class="ie responsive-map $variable2" %3$s>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
    <div $variable3 class="responsive-map $variable4" $variable5>
<!--<![endif]-->
        <iframe src="$variable6"></iframe>
    </div>
EOF
```

Compared with multiline double quoted string, it improves readability, will try explain by example:

```
$format = "<!--[if lt IE 9]>    <--- breaks indention
    <div $variable1 class=\"ie responsive-map $variable2\" %3$s>  <-- need to escape "
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
    <div $variable3 class=\"responsive-map $variable4\" $variable5>
<!--<![endif]-->
        <iframe src=\"$variable6\"></iframe>
    </div>";
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that heredoc allowed to inject variables, admittedly I basically only knew it existed. This will certainly help with readability. But it seems for complex strings concatenation can't be avoided and has to be well structured to avoid the mess I had at the start.

Comment: yes, heredocs are nice. unfortunately the syntax highlighter on stackoverflow messes them up. They would look much more readable in most text editors...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want with PHP. If readability is the most important thing for you simply use HEREDOC or NOWDOC.

```
<?php

$output = <<<HTML
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <div {$var} class="ie responsive-map {$var}" {$var}>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
  <div {$var} class="responsive-map {$var}" {$var}>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <iframe src="{$var}"></iframe>
  </div>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are targeting the view part of the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). In this case you could do use it just like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div <?= $format ?> class="ie responsive-map <?= $id ?>" <?= $icon ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
    <div <?= $format ?> class="responsive-map <?= $id ?>" <?= $icon ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <iframe src="<?= $height ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

It's important that you hold this source in a seperate file form our controller and models which hold the actual logic and data.

Here you can find an introduction: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

Comment: See my comment on the question: directly outputting HTML is sadly not an option.